# Get relation count Laravel JSON

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have a Post model where has many comments via hasMany('App/Comment') relation. I am trying to return the number of comments in JSON format. The response I would like to get is like

```
comments: [...],
numComments: 5,
...
```

I am able to return the comments but I don't know whether there is an easy way to get number of comments with eager loading.

```
Post::whereIn('user_id', $ids)->with('comments')->get();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution [here](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/).